I have a problem with windows xterm in airgeddon
VMware
Linux 2024.3
This problem appeared with me after updating Kali Linux windows xterm It became small and I had to enlarge it manually. When I search for networks or attack the evil twin, the windows that appear automatically are very small. They used to appear normally before the update. What is the solution to the problem? 

what is the picture supposed to show?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Supposedly when you trigger the Evil Twin Attack in AirGaddon  Six windows appear on the screen, sharing the screen space, and each one of them has space, three of them share the right part and three of them share the left part, but in my case the six windows appear in a small size and I have to enlarge each window separately.

At first they appeared normally, but after I updated Kali, this problem appeared. What is the solution?

I've only just seen your comments, @Ahmedmagdy. Please add information to your question so everything is in the same place. It's too easy to miss comments and they can be deleted at zero notice too. Make it easy for us to help you

I seem to have the same issue here on my kali install. My system is a Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ALC6. I am using the latest version on kali and seem to have this specific issue. The resolution is set as 1920x1080 detected by airgeddon and i have no other display connected to my system. This only happens when the airgeddon launches the xterm terminal. If you normally use the xterm terminal it is fine. I have tried airgeddon on ParrotOS the security edition is works there. I have tried reinstalling kali and tried the liveboot version too but same issue. I think the launch size is hardcoded  in the kali repo for airgeddon making it appear like that  on 1920x1080p display i am gonna test the live boot on a vmware vm to see how it goes. If you want to replicate the issue get a copy of the new kali and install airgeddon after installing kali or livebooting
